# Consecutive ContinueWith statements

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have

```
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
       doSomething();
    }).ContinueWith (t => {
       doSomething2();
    }).ContinueWith (x => {
       doSomething3();
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext ());
```

Are these methods executed in consecutive order? I.e., `doSomething()` is executed and once that finishes then `doSomething2()` starts and once that finishes, `doSomething3()` starts

If they are not executed in consecutive order, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Posts about `ContinueWith` would not be out of date just because new versions of C# have come out since then. A new release of .NET does not change the fundamental behavior of an  already-released API, otherwise noone would accept the new release.

Comment: `await` is better way of doing this but you are not interested in it (since `ContinueWith` *are* executed in consecutive order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these kind of questions, a simple approach is to write a quick test:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Starting Main: Thread ID {1}", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var finalTask = Task.Delay(500)
            .ContinueWith(_ => {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: First Continue With: Task ID {1}, Thread ID {2}", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, Task.CurrentId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            })
            .ContinueWith(_ => {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: Second Continue With: Task ID {1}, Thread ID {2}", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay, Task.CurrentId, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            });;

        finalTask.Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: Finished!", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
    }
}
```

This produces the following. By looking at the times, this confirms that the second `ContinueWith` takes place only after the first has completed.

```
02:03:16.1360139: Starting Main: Thread ID 107
02:03:16.6407471: First Continue With: Task ID 1, Thread ID 272
02:03:17.6514780: Second Continue With: Task ID 2, Thread ID 272
02:03:18.6592219: Finished!
```

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gw4hW0)

Answer (score 2):

Correct. It will always execute in the order. ContinueWith will run only after the calling task has been completed.

> Creates a continuation that executes asynchronously when the target Task completes and returns a value.

[msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: *"ContinueWith will run on the same thread"* That is not correct, it may be likely or even the normal case but there are situations where it will not. It all depends on the task schedueler you have associated with the ContinueWith

Comment: Your update is still incorrect. See "[ContinueWith is Dangerous, Too](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html)", the `.ContinueWith` will run with `TaskScheduler.Current` which can cause things to run on the UI thread when you do not expect them to. Your answer is describing the behavior of `.ContinueWith(/*...*/, TaskScheduler.Default)` which is ***NOT*** what the OP is using in his post.

Comment: My previous edit was taken from CLR with c# (page 696).I removed that part since that is not what OP had asked.